# Java Non repeating sequence algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Hey everyone So I am making an application that with loop through an array of 1625 words & create a 12 word string. The problem is that a single word can't show up twice in the string.

```
(Numbered) ex.  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1625  
then   
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, ...  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 1625  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ..., ...  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1625, 1624  
then   
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 11  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 12  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, ...  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 1625  
0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 12    
And so on......
```

I am having a very hard time figuring out the math behind this algorithm as I would prefer to avoid "if" statements. If someone would be able to help me that would be great.

(Note the numbers above are the indexes in the array that holds words)

EDIT: SIMPLE OUTPUT:
0, 1, 2
0, 1, 3
0, 1, 4
0, 1, 5
0, 1, 6
0, 1, ...
0, 1, 9
0, 2, 1
0, 2, 3
0, 2, 4
0, 2, 5
0, 2, ...
0, 9, ...
0, 9, 1
0, 9, 2
0, 9, 3
0, 9, ...
1, 0, 2
1, 0, 3
1, 0, 4
1, 0, ...
1, 2, 3
And so on

Comment: Doesn't this question point yo HashSet?

Comment: You seem to be saying that you want to print *every* permutation of *every* combination of 12 distinct words from among a list of 1625 different words.  That's simply not feasible.  There are well over 10^37 such permutations.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's not feasible to do such a thing but my goal is to make an algorithm that can produce such a result given enough time or computation power

Comment: Look up an algorithm for computing permutations (or write one *de novo*).  Then modify it to return the result after selecting only the initial 12 items.

Comment: How much time are you offered to run this algorithm? Have you try the simplest way (nest for or recursive)? I think it's not easy to run this with normal loop

Comment: This will be running for ~5 months on a massive sever 24/7 I understand that the number of combos will be 341 undecillion but my goal is to get as many possible combos in the time I have regardless of finishing. The smallest code inefficiency would set the results back in the trillions.

Comment: Then maybe Java isn't the best option?

Comment: What are you going to do with these permutations? Just generate them and store them somewhere? What's the point when you could just write an algorithm that will let you look up any permutation in the sequence and output it?

Comment: My goal is to create a rainbow table of some sort.

Comment: There are A(1626,12)~3*10^38 arrangements. Good generator can produce 100 million arrangements in second, and for 86400 seconds in day you have to wait 38*10^24 days. In 5 months you could get only negligible part of all possible arrangements. What is a reason for resource and time wasting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a very optional solution as I feel its brute force way of doing it.
 Would this work for you?
You can replace the `TOTAL_SIZE` variable to 1626 (as you want 1625 to get printed as well.) and `CHUNK_SIZE` to 12.

```
public class TestClass {
    static int TOTAL_SIZE = 5;
    static int CHUNK_SIZE = 3;
    static int[] wordArray = new int[TOTAL_SIZE];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_SIZE; i++) {
            wordArray[i] = i;
        }

        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] visitedIndexes = new int[TOTAL_SIZE];
        printAllValues(newList, visitedIndexes);
    }


    private static void printAllValues(List<Integer> newList, int[] visitedIndexes) {
        if(newList.size() == CHUNK_SIZE) {
            newList.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
            System.out.println(""); // new line
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_SIZE; i++) {
            if (visitedIndexes[i] != 1) {
                visitedIndexes[i] = 1;
                newList.add(wordArray[i]);
                printAllValues(newList, visitedIndexes);
                newList.remove((Integer) wordArray[i]);
                visitedIndexes[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :** For array size of 5 and word size of 3.

```
012
013
014
021
023
024
031
032
034
041
042
043
102
103
104
120
123
124
130
132
134
140
142
143
201
203
204
210
213
214
230
231
234
240
241
243
301
302
304
310
312
314
320
321
324
340
341
342
401
402
403
410
412
413
420
421
423
430
431
432
```

**Description :**

1. Take each value from the original list.
2. For each character appended, populate every combination of remaining characters.
3. Retry this logic, by removing the skipping this appended character and trying out every possible combination.

This logic can be optimized:

1. by checking up front as to how many values are left in `for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_SIZE; i++)` loop and break out if there aren't enough values to go ahead (i.e., `if((list.size() + (TOTAL_SIZE-i)) < CHUNK_SIZE) break;`

Also, for a huge data the recursion might just blow up.

Comment: I think you miss some cases. 012 021 102 102 201 210 are all accepted

Comment: This is the point I am at right now but it has the wrong output, the output should be:                                                                                012
013
014
021
023
031
123
124
132
230

Comment: Ah!! Thanks for the inputs. I updated the answer, the loop should start from 0th location and skip already processed ones.
We could maintain another index array to see which all indexes are present in the list, instead of doing the list look up to optimize this further.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, but is there a way of avoiding checking the Array/ Hashmap and instead using math to solve this algorithm as I know this will be a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

This code can run on small set. But I am not sure how long it take in huge data in your case. Hope it help!

```
static int STRING_SIZE = 3; //12 in your  case
static int MAX_VAL = 10; //1625 in your case
static Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fillSet();
}

static void fillSet() {
    if (set.size() == STRING_SIZE) {
        System.out.println(set);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VAL; i++) {
        if (set.contains(i))
            continue;
        set.add(i);

        fillSet();

        set.remove(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, but is there a way of avoiding checking the Array/ Hashmap and instead using math to solve this algorithm as I know this will be a faster way.